# Dynamic library not loading in R binary package build

Tags: r, dll, compilation, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to build a package with compiled `C` code in `R` using 'RStudio' and 'devtools' in a Windows environment.

Only one of the function uses the `C` code in `src` folder. The source package works fine. I can use all the functions. I am able to compile the C code using `devtools::document()` and the corresponding `.dll` and `.o` file also appears in the `src` folder. Then I can load the code using `dev_tools::load_all` or `Ctrl+Shift+L` and run all the functions.

However when I am building and reloading the package using `Ctrl+Shift+B`, I am not able to use the particular function. The function is missing from the package even thought the documentation is retained. I also get the error telling that the corresponding `.dll` is not loaded.

```
Error in library.dynam.unload(name, system.file(package = name)) : 
  DLL ‘mypackage.dll’ was not loaded
```

I get the same results when I am using `devtools::build` with `binary=TRUE`.

However I can find the `.dll` file in the library `Documents\R\win-library\3.0\mypackage\libs\i386\mypackage.dll`. Why is this dynamic library from compiled code not being loaded?

PS: 1) `devtools::has_devel()` is giving `TRUE` 
    2) I am forced to use `.C` instead of `.Call`.

This is the result of the `R CMD INSTALL`

```
* installing to library 'C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.0'
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/mypackage/libs/i386
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (mypackage)
```

Comment: The `make:` line implies that your source code has .o or .dll files, maybe in mypackage/i386/ that are 'newer' than the source code files that they are based on; remove them (the .o and .dll files) from the package source and try again. If you have a Makevars or Makefile, then be sure you know what you're doing...

Comment: @MartinMorgan I have tried that. Still facing the problem. I am not using Makevars or Makefile.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this on Windows 10 with R 3.5 by adding the following function to a file in the `R/` folder.

```
.onUnload <- function (libpath) { library.dynam.unload("mypackage", libpath)}
```

[Here is the reference where I found it](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#c-best-practices).

Comment: For the libpath in this example, do you put in the location of the DLL file? So it would be "lib/x64/myDLL.dll" or do you just type in libpath. I tried both and neither worked for me. I looked at the reference you provided and it is very unclear.

Comment: I just type in libpath, exactly as written there. You can find the exact code here https://github.com/ocbe-uio/BayesMallows/blob/9a74609b46668fd7b85546981727a7afe4d56fa4/R/misc.R#L7-L9