# Building R package with DLLs

Tags: r, package

I am attempting to create a binary package that contains precompiled `.dll` files which the package relies on to function. I have the file `tkogl2.dll` which needs to be loaded upon usage of the package. After creating the package and attempting to build using `devtools::build(binary = TRUE)` I receive the following error:

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for 'GUImorphTest' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
    DLL 'tkogl2.dll' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
   错误: 载入失败
   停止执行
   *** arch - x64
   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'GUImorphTest' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
    DLL 'tkogl2.dll' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
   错误: 载入失败
   停止执行
   ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
```

This is most likely due to the `NAMESPACE` file, though I am a novice in this process, so I am not entirely sure what it should consist. It currently only contains `useDynLib(tkogl2.dll)` which I found to put there from googling. It could also be where I put the .dll in my package. I simply created a libs folder as seen here:[image]
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

edit:
Here is onload fct

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    chname <- "tkogl2"
    file.ext <- .Platform$dynlib.ext #dll file
    dlname <- paste(chname, file.ext, sep = "")
    if (is.character(.Platform$r_arch) && .Platform$r_arch != "")
        path <- file.path("libs", .Platform$r_arc, dlname)
    else path <- file.path("libs", dlname)
    file <- system.file(path, package = pkgname, lib.loc = libname)[1] #grabs full file name
    print(file)
    tryCatch(tcl("load", file, "Tkogl2"),
             error = function(e)
             warning("loading tkogl2 failed", call. = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: you try it with the full path?

Comment: You shouldn't include the `.dll` in the name, and write your own `install.libs.R` file to install it.  See "Writing R Extensions".

Comment: Have you looked at, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057164/8386140 ?

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, I have an .onLoad function. I will share it

Comment: [An example](https://github.com/stla/jsonAccess).

Comment: [Anotherexample](https://github.com/stla/expansions), including Windows DLLs. For Windows, you must have the folders `inst/libs/i386` and `inst/libs/x64`.